# Shortcut key for *now*

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision

I'm looking for the shortcut to enter the date and time of *now* in Microsoft Navision. I know about 't', which will enter today's date, but that leaves the time-part empty.

So basically: What key goes at the place of the ?

```
Key     Result
't'     06/03/15 00:00:00  
?       06/03/15 14:36:28
```

Note: The exact letter depends on the language of your specific Navision client. In english, the letter is 't'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google can be your friend after all. Seems I had to threaten it with a question here first.

As found on [KRIKI’S DYNAMICS NAV BLOG](http://mibuso.com/blogs/kriki/2010/05/14/current-date-current-time-current-datetime/) the answer is

```
t t
```

Quoted from the blog:

> Everyone (at least, I think so) knows that you can use ‘t’ (or ‘w’ for workdate) in a datefield to get the current system date.
>   Not everyone knows that you can use ‘t’ in a time field to get the system time.
>   But do you know you can use ‘t t’ to get the current system date + time in a datetime field? The first t  is for the date and the second for the time. And you can also use ‘w t’ to have the workdate + system time.

Comment: Note this depends on your navision language. The German Navision (as used in the original question) uses `h z` instead of `t t`.

Comment: Actually the NAV in the original question is the english version, but the dutch language pack was installed as well. I have no idea what the 'h' is supposed to mean in dutch...